# Obj-C, when are interface variables lost, when pushing and dismissing back from another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a data maintenance screen and I have some selection screens which I push on to the navigation stack, I then dismiss once a selection is made.

When will the interface variables on my maintenance screen be lost?

I didn't think they would be lost.
But I'm getting some weird results.

Comment: Variables do not get lost. Perhaps you could elaborate on these "weird results"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they won't be lost until its `viewDidUnload` is called.. if you have set them to nil in `viewDiDunload` ... they will sure get lost in dealloc..

basically if you present a modal view or push a view on above a  present view(lets say A) .. then A variables are still in memory...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process a property from a viewController that is being popped off the stack of a navigationController, you would want to use the delegation pattern. The delegate would be the viewController that initiated the maintenance viewController. When popping the maintenance viewController off the navigation stack, it would call it's delegate (the viewController that initiated) to do some processing on the maintenance viewController's property, before it left memory.